# Problems with Oledb and DATETIME

Tags: c#, oledb

I need some help.this is my code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Request " + "WHERE _Date >= " + "@Dt", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dt", OleDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters["@Dt"].Value = DateTime.Now;
using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{ }
```

But it returns an exception:

> "Syntax error in query expression '_Date >= @Dt'." OleDb Exception

and with this code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Request " + "WHERE _Date > " + "'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") +"'", con);
using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{  }
```

it returns

> "Syntax error in query expression '_Date > '2014-08-08 10:55:04''."

What's wrong here?

Comment: I would avoid Column names that have an underscore in front like that, and I would also try to give it a better name, like RequestDate.  Try putting the field in brackets: [_Date].

Comment: @LarsTech, Change column names and work. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the underscore, the name Date is a reserved word, so you should probably place the field name in brackets:

```
WHERE [_Date] > @Dt
```

It's best to avoid reserved words and use a better description for the field name, like RequestDate.  I would also avoid starting a column name with an underscore.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Request] WHERE [_Date] >= @Date", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: @user886550 please give the full error description.

Comment: @user886550 if this was right then click on right button for set it answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exposing your SQL to injection by concatinating your sql together, use a placeholder for the parameter.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Request WHERE _Date > ?", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
```